# I can't get my Thread or loop functioning properly

Tags: java, android, sdk, timepicker

So I have been working on this project all day because I am trying to learn about the timePicker and dealing with time in java and with the android sdk. So right now I have the following set up:

```
package com.dicamillo.alarm;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AlarmlockActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TimePicker tp;
    Button set;
    int hour;
    int minuet;
    DigitalClock dc;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TextView complete;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tpAlarmTime);
        set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSet);
        dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minuet = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        complete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        set.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSet:

            Thread alarmstart = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (tp.getCurrentHour().intValue() != hour
                            && tp.getCurrentMinute().intValue() != minuet) {
                        tp.getCurrentHour().intValue();
                        tp.getCurrentMinute().intValue();
                        if (tp.getCurrentHour().intValue() == hour
                                && tp.getCurrentMinute().intValue() == minuet) {
                            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                                    AlarmlockActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
                            mp.start();
                            complete.setText("COmpleted!");

                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            alarmstart.start();
            break;
        }
    }
```

and when the selected time reaches the current time nothing happens like it should supposed to. Am I missing something in the thread? Or I am doing this completely wrong. Any help work be great. I know I have been asking for a lot of help today but all I want to do is learn. =)

Comment: People don't want to stare at 50 lines of code. Reduce it as far as possible, please.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed several mistakes in your code.

1) No need for a seperate thread.

2) No need for a while loop because you are entering an infinite loop there if set hour and minute are not equal to current time.

3) You are not using DigitalClock at all. Why is the variable there?

4) Even if you enter the while loop, you are calling

```
tp.getCurrentHour().intValue();
tp.getCurrentMinute().intValue();
```

which are not assigned to any variable so they serve no purpose.

5) Your condition in if clause will never be satisfied because you wouldn't be in the while loop if it was satisfied.

6) No need for switch-case because you only have one button.

7) In the end, the only thing you need to have in your onClick method is:

```
tp.clearFocus();// allows reading the value set if entered by keyboard

if (tp.getCurrentHour().intValue() == hour && tp.getCurrentMinute().intValue() == minuet) {
         MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(AlarmlockActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
         mp.start();
         complete.setText("COmpleted!");
```

}

I hope you are also aware of the hour and minute when you are launching the application because if you do not know about the time when you launch it, then you will have difficult time trying to match the time in the time picker.

**EDIT:** `hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);` will return you the time in 12hr format. If your TimePicker is set to 24hr format, then it will not work for times when you launch your application at PM time. You should use [HOUR_OF_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) field of Calendar instead.

You can also print hour and minute variables to a textView to make sure about their values or use a debugger to compare them to what you get from getCurrentXXX() methods from TimePicker, since you want to match to them in TimePicker.

Comment: I made the corrections and nothing and adding the @Override gives me an error because the onClick method is not a superClass, and if I ignore that still nothing just like before.

Comment: Ok, no need for Override then. Please see my edit and a little update on 7).